# Conditionally Loading jQuery custom scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of, I am using jQuery-1.8.2...

I was wondering how can I load custom scripts from other server and from main server as backup.

Just like loading jquery or jquery tools or jquery ui... and so on.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="<?php echo $siteURL; ?>/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

I am not really sure how can I do this for custom script... For example for the link below.

```
<script src="//dvL-den.net/custom/random-script.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code snippet works by detecting if the `jQuery` global object has been created. That's all. (It presumes that no other scripts are creating any global variables named 'jQuery', but that's a reasonable -- although not infallible -- presumption.)

You need to do the same -- check to see if some *unique* global variable, object, or property in your custom script exists, and if not, assume the script hasn't been called. It can be anything, even a bizarre variable like `var window._this_is_a_test = true` which is set solely for this purpose.

Comment: Aham I see... I didn't knew that.
Thank you so much for the help Blazemonger. Will check as correct as soon as possible!